# In Rails App: Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes

In my Rails App, I'm messing around with routes etc.

What happens is in my create and update controller I changed the redirect to something else and then this comes up in Chrome:

```
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending   
any data.
```

After I hit refresh the app continues as per normal. Why is this happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm getting the same error on a ruby on rails website that we use in our organization. It's the Canvas LMS from Instructure. I wanna open a support case about it but I'm not sure if they'll just believe me so I'm researching about it. It seems to only happen to me the first time I hit it during the day.